# C# pass a DataRow[] variable from code behind to .netpage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to pass a `protected DataRow[] msgArray;` from code-behind to the .net page.

`msgArray` contains rows from a DB table that I selected, when I do `Response.Write(msgArray[0]["comment"])` it outputs correctly what I have stored in the comment column in my DB.
The problem is that I cannot do the same in my .net page when I load the page where I do this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="commentSection" runat="server">
        <%= msgArray[0]["comment"] %>
    </asp:Panel>
```

I get a  `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

What am I doing wrong ?

This is my code-behind(`.cs`) :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Groups
{
    public partial class Group : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd;
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader reader;
        String queryStr;
        String gname;
        String gtype;
        String uname;
        DataTable group = new DataTable();
        DataTable msg = new DataTable();

        protected DataRow[] msgArray; 



        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String id = Request.QueryString["id"];

            if (id != null)
            {
                String connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GroupsConnString"].ToString();
                conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connString);

                conn.Open();
                queryStr = "SELECT g.*, (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM app_groups.users_groups_leg ugl WHERE ugl.id_group = g.id) as member_count FROM app_groups.groups g WHERE g.id = " + id;
                cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(queryStr, conn);

                group.Load(reader = cmd.ExecuteReader());
                var groupArray = group.AsEnumerable().ToArray();
                reader.Close();

                int member_count = 0;
                int.TryParse(groupArray[0]["member_count"].ToString(), out member_count);

                Panel grInfo = new Panel();
                grInfo.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/><div class='panel panel-primary'><div class='panel-heading'><h2>" + groupArray[0]["group_name"] + "</h2></div><div class='panel-body'><span>Categorie: <span class='title'>" + groupArray[0]["group_type"] + "</span></span><br/><span class='membrii'>" + (member_count == 1 ? member_count + " membru" : member_count + " membri") + "</span><br/><span>Fondat pe: " + ConvertUnixTimeStamp(groupArray[0]["founded"].ToString()) + "</span><br/></div></div>"));
                groupInfo.Controls.Add(grInfo);

                conn.Close();

                showComments();
            }

        }

        public static DateTime? ConvertUnixTimeStamp(string unixTimeStamp)
        {
            return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(unixTimeStamp) + 3600*2);
        }

        public DataRow[] showComments()
        {
            String id = Request.QueryString["id"];
            if (id != null)
            {
                String connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GroupsConnString"].ToString();
                conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connString);

                conn.Open();
                queryStr = "SELECT gc.* FROM app_groups.group_comments gc WHERE gc.id_group = " + id;
                cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(queryStr, conn);

                msg.Load(reader = cmd.ExecuteReader());
                msgArray = msg.AsEnumerable().ToArray();
                reader.Close();

                Response.Write(msgArray[0]["comment"]);

                /*Panel grComments = new Panel();
                grComments.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(""));
                groupInfo.Controls.Add(grComments);*/
            }

            return msgArray;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you put breakpoint in .cs page and .aspx page, which one is being hit first?

Comment: Why are you putting the comments in a datatable?

Comment: @Kami, because I need them there, I need to pass them to .aspx page so I can iterate there and add them to divs, it's easier this way, instead of creating `new Panels` in code behind and adding content to each panel

Comment: You can access your commentSection panel from code behind and write the comments right into it.

Comment: @AnupSharma I don't know how to add a breakpoint to see that, I'm a newbie in .net, my main webdevelopment tool is PHP

Comment: PLease go to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k80ex6de(v=vs.90).aspx to see how to put breakpoint in visual studio

Comment: @Kami I know I can access it, but to add a div or a button etc to commentSection I need to created objects with `new Panel`,`new Button` which is not what I want, I just want to add the button or div directly like you do it in HTML

Comment: Use a repeater, put your div or button in the itemtemplate and in your code behind assign the datatable as datasource to the repeater. If you check out my profile, you can send me an email with your code and I can show you an easy way.

Comment: You can also see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx

Comment: @Kami isn't it easier to pass the `msgArray` to the .aspx page and iterate there over the array?

Comment: You cannot pass the msgArray to the aspx. Your datatable has to  be defined in your aspx code in <% .. %>

Comment: @kami can u ilustrate that in an answer?

Comment: I don't put my sql queries in the aspx page. I create a separate data layer and access that from the aspx page. I'll show you how.

Comment: @Kami I managed to do it, I passed a `DataTable` variable to the .aspx page and then looped on it, it works, thanks :D

Comment: I'm trying to add my code in the answer for you but it is not working as I want the formatting to be. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100239/discussion-between-kami-and-southpaw93).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new class dataAccess.cs

```
using System;
using System.Data;

namespace Groups
{
    public class dataAccess
    {
        public List<string> GetComments()
        {
            String connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GroupsConnString"].ToString();
            conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connString);

            try
            {
                MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader reader;
                DataTable msg = new DataTable();
                conn.Open();
                List<string> comments = new List<string>();
                queryStr = "SELECT gc.* FROM app_groups.group_comments gc WHERE gc.id_group = " + id;
                cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(queryStr, conn);

                msg.Load(reader = cmd.ExecuteReader());
                foreach(DataRow dr in msg.Rows)
                {
                    comments.Add(dr["comment"]);
                }
                reader.Close();
                return comments;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the ASPX page

```
<asp:Panel ID="commentSection" runat="server">
    <%
        var data = Groups.dataAccess.GetComments();
        foreach(string c in data)
        {
            Response.Write("<p>" + c + "</p>");
        }
    %>
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to ASP.NET Page Life cycle, your method `showComments()` will be called after the `<%= msgArray[0]["comment"] %>` part. Hence it won't be available there.
Best way is to have a control like Label in your .aspx page and update the text property from `showComments()` method.